# Oracle SQL: ANY + IS NULL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I need to check several fields with NULL. Of course I can do it with `OR`.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE f1 IS NULL OR f2 IS NULL OR f3 IS NULL
```

But there is `ANY` which works fine with logical operations.

Is it possible to do something like that in Oracle's SQL?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ANY (f1, f2, f3) IS NULL
```

I use Oracle 12c.

Comment: This is a good question. Your syntax looks fine, but is not supported by Oracle SQL, unfiortunately. However, this is not about PL/SQL, which is Oracle's programming language inside the DBMS. It is about Oracle's SQL. I've hence removed all PL/SQL references from your question and tagged it with SQL instead.

Comment: I've just checked with other DBMS. The syntax, as good as it looks, is not supported in MySQL, SQL Server or PostgreSQL either.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner Oh, you are right. It's about SQL not PLSQL.

Comment: Stick with `is null`.  Oracle can take advantage of indexes with `or` conditions -- and you usually want to keep that option open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the inverse of Tim's anser, you can use GREATEST or LEAST to look where any value is NULL

```
select * from dual where greatest('a',2,3,null) is null;
```

Comment: Great solution. I've always considered it a nuisance that these functions return null when one of the arguments is null. But in this situation that comes handy :-)

Comment: This seems to work when mixing numbers and strings, as numbers seem to be converted to strings. But it won't work if there's e.g. a `DATE` column involved.

Comment: I have VARCHAR2 fields in the list and it works fine

Answer (score 3):

#### A trick in Oracle using expressions or functions:

If those are all numeric values, you could just use `+`:

```sql
with t(a, b, c) as (
  select 1, 2, 3 from dual union all 
  select null, 2, 3 from dual union all 
  select null, null, 3 from dual
)
select *
from t
where a + b + c is null;
```

It yields

```
A|B|C|
-|-|-|
 |2|3|
 | |3|
```

Also, the less readable `DECODE` function could be used, or `GREATEST` as [Gary already showed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61516364/521799):

```sql
decode(null, a, 1, b, 1, c, 1, 0) = 1;
```

#### Using `MINUS`

You can use `(a, b, c) = ((a, b, c))` to check if none of the values is `NULL`, in case of which the predicate yields `NULL`. Unfortunately, as Oracle doesn't know `BOOLEAN` types, you cannot `NULL` check that predicate itself (and `LNNVL` doesn't seem to work with the above condition), but you could use `MINUS`:

```sql
with t(a, b, c) as (
  select 1, 2, 3 from dual union all 
  select null, 2, 3 from dual union all 
  select null, null, 3 from dual
)
select *
from t
minus
select *
from t
where (a, b, c) = ((a, b, c)); -- None of the values is NULL
```

This is obviously a slow solution in many cases, so not good.

#### Standard SQL:

It's worth mentioning that standard SQL (e.g. implemented by PostgreSQL, but not Oracle) supports null predicates on row value expressions like this:

```sql
not ((a, b, c) is not null)
```

The "double negative" is necessary because the truth table shows that `not x is null` and `x is not null` are not the same thing ([source](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/conditional-expressions/null-predicate-degree-n/)):

```
+-----------------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+
| Expression            | R IS NULL | R IS NOT NULL | NOT R IS NULL | NOT R IS NOT NULL |
+-----------------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+
| degree 1: null        | true      | false         | false         |  true             |
| degree 1: not null    | false     | true          | true          |  false            |
| degree > 1: all null  | true      | false         | false         |  true             |
| degree > 1: some null | false     | false         | true          |  true             |
| degree > 1: none null | false     | true          | true          |  false            |
+-----------------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks Lukas. I have VARCHAR2 fields and it looks like  "USING +" approach works too. "Standard SQL" approach gives me an error: 00920. 00000 -  "invalid relational operator"

Comment: You shouldn't use `+` with `VARCHAR2` fields, or you might get number conversion errors as Oracle applies `TO_NUMBER()` on each value. In that case, the `GREATEST()` approach is better, but the best approach is really to use ordinary `OR` predicates! I just wanted to add the "Standard SQL" section for completeness' sake 1) in case Oracle ever implements that, 2) in case someone visits this answer using some other RDBMS.

Comment:  I've allowed myself to rework your second approach :)

Answer (score 2):

Comparing entire rows with row constructor syntax:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN (f1,f2,f3)=((f1,f2,f3)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS all_non_nulls  
             FROM dual) s
WHERE s.all_non_nulls = 0; -- 1
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a16759013e6252650f17637543438752)**

`(f1,f2,f3)` -> here goes column list